# Django REST Framework - Best way to serialize related objects with Model Serializer and validate objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Let's say that i have these two models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)

class Bar(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And i want to create a serializer that validates a Foo object with a list of Bar's, something like this

```
{ 
   "a": "1",
   "b": ["1", "2", "3"]
}
```

What is the best way to serialize them together using ModelSerializer? And also, how can i make the b list mandatory for every object?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the better solution:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/